Complexity of finding graph automorphism group vs. canonization
Given a generating set for the automorphism group of a graph, can we efficiently find a canonical labeling? What about the other way around?
Both problems of finding a graph automorphism group and graph canonization are GI-hard. Can we reduce one of the two to the other, and if so at what complexity?
For context: The nauty and bliss libraries can heuristically solve both simultaneously, while saucy solves the former but not canonization.

Finding the generators of the automorphism group of a graph is in fact GI-complete (under poly-time Turing reductions) - goes back to Mathon '79 and the proof is not hard.
Canonization is not known to be equivalent to deciding isomorphism, but in many cases isomorphism algorithms have been upgraded to canonization using similar techniques as the isomorphism algorithm. (For more on the relationship between deciding equivalence vs computing a canonical form, see: What is the most efficient algorithm for deciding if an element is the least in its orbit? and Example where equivalence is easy but finding class representative is hard.)

Thanks for another fantastic answer, Joshua! (: So GI-completeness implies that Babai's 2016 GI algorithm allows us to find the generators of a graph's automorphism group in quasi-polynomial time (+ the same for the graph automorphism problem)?

Yes. (It does not give you canonization, but Babai had a follow-up paper in STOC the following year (IIRC) where he upgraded his algorithm to a canonization algorithm.)

Wow. In that case, it looks like the wiki articles on graph automorphisms and canonization are seriously outdated.

Found your reference: Canonical Form for Graphs in Quasipolynomial Time. Babai seems to like keeping things "preliminary". (:
